# Data from Mysql, input into various text fields

Tags: mysql, search, textbox

I have an Order page which contains various text fields for the user to input their data.  Once they submit that page, all that data is put into a Mysql database.

I am wondering if it is possible to have a search page, where I can enter say an address that I want to search for in that database.  Once a match is found, can I take all that data matching that order and repopulate the order page text fields?

Comment: Yes, but more information would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It is, using a LIKE clause:

```
SELECT * FROM order WHERE address LIKE "%address_value%"
```

The `%` is a wildcard that matches any number of characters (`_` matches a single character).

You can use this to populate fields.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

And to head off the inevitable next question, here's a basic skeleton:

```
$sql = "SELECT some,fields,from,the.database FROM yourtable WHERE ...";
$stmt = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($stmt)) {
   echo $row['some'];  // spit out the contents of the 'some' field.
}
```